# EE2 Control Panel Error: Unable to load the following extension file: ext.rte.php

Tags: control-panel

I am trying to migrate EE2 application to a new server. There are a bunch of errors. When I try to open the CP(EE system folder), it shows up without loading CSS correctly. After I login, it gives error message below:

> **Error**
>
> **Unable to load the following extension file:**
>
> **ext.rte.php**

[image]
[image]

Does anyone have an idea how to solve that error? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Reupload your themes folders and/or check file permissions of said folder

Comment: Thanks for quick replying! I have reuploaded the theme folder and changed the file permission to 777. Still not working. I was wondering where is the file that called this module. Maybe the path is wrong.

Comment: If the CP isn't loading CSS then either the files are corrupt or the paths are incorrect. Using the network panel (or equivalent in your browser's dev tools) look for 404 for missing files.

Comment: Thanks Stu! The tricky part is there's no browser's dev tool can display that as EE system will not even try to load it. So it will not show any 404 error message. However, I fixed that css issue. What I did is changing the base url in config file. And EE gets the correct path and it works.  

Now I am having another issue, which is I cannot find where does the extension.php trying to loading in

`$path = ee()->addons->_packages[$name]['extension']['path'];` in **extension.php file**

Maybe I should open a new thread.